# Django tests failing after unique_together error catch

Tags: django, testing

Writing my tests for a certain part of my Django application I am trying to test if a unique_together error message pops up on my API. This is the test I am running:

```
re = self.c.patch('/api/me/dashboards/' + str(default_id) + '/', {'widgets': [{
    'name': 'Testwidget 2',
    'type': 1,
    'coord_x': 1,
    'coord_y': 1
}]}, content_type='application/json')
self.assertEqual(500, re.status_code)
self.assertEqual(
   re.content, b'{"message":"UNIQUE constraint failed: dashboard_widget.coord_x, dashboard_widget.coord_y, dashboard_widget.dashboard_id","status":500,"error":true,"detail":""}')
```

It works fine, but after that no matter whicht test I am running it states `django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.`

If I remove all tests after this, there is no error message or similar. The API endpoint works otherwise, it is just the test that messes up. Also I did this with a similar test, which should raise a `Validationerror` and this test behaves the same: Everything is fine but the subsequent test is failing with the error.

**Edit**
This is the serializer, in case anyone wonders. The viewset is just a default GenericViewSet and using the UpdateModelMixin to call this.

```
class DashboardSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    widgets = WidgetSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Dashboard
        exclude = []

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        widgets = validated_data.pop('widgets')
        if not self.partial:
            Widget.objects.filter(dashboard=instance).delete()
        for wid in widgets:
            wid['type'] = wid['type'].id
            if 'id' in wid:
                wid_instance = get_object_or_404(Widget, id=wid['id'])
                serializer = WidgetSerializer(
                    wid_instance, data=wid, partial=True)
            else:
                serializer = WidgetSerializer(
                    data=wid, context={'dashboard': instance})
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
        return super().update(instance, validated_data)
```

Comment: Can you share the view behind this test?

Comment: Should have stated this, sorry. It is all standard rest_framework using the UpdateModelMixin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason those operations only succeed, if the transactions are done atomically:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    re = self.c.patch('/api/me/dashboards/' + str(default_id) + '/', {'widgets': [{'name': 'Testwidget 2', 'type': 1, 'coord_x': 1, 'coord_y': 1}]}, content_type='application/json')
    self.assertEqual(500, re.status_code)
    self.assertEqual(re.content, b'{"message":"UNIQUE constraint failed: dashboard_widget.coord_x, dashboard_widget.coord_y, dashboard_widget.dashboard_id","status":500,"error":true,"detail":""}')
```

Maybe this is only if using SQLite, but this worked for me.